# Print from Flash-embedded website without Windows print dialog

Tags: windows-7, printing

I'm building a kiosk-style web page (full screen) that has a print function. It is built in Flash, and will run on Windows 7. I need it to automatically print an image from the SWF (not the whole web page), without the print dialog popup (I want to avoid any user interaction).

Is there a way to bypass or disable the print dialog popup? I have access to the OS settings to configure it any way i need to.

Comment: do you only have control of the website, or both the website and the computer they are viewing the website from?

Comment: i have control of both. i can basically do anything. thanks.

Comment: what technologies are you using to create the site?

Comment: it's Flash (SWF) embedded into an HTML page, like a regular website. i can use JS. i can use any version of IE.

Comment: I saw something about printing a specific URL without actually navigating there, but I can't seem to find it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Best thing that I could find on the internet, I don't know if this is something that you can implement somehow and I haven't tested this either.

it is an answer to [Print directly from browser without print popup window [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124848/1214743)

It mentions using VBScript and the post is 5 years old (give or take) so I don't know that it will work for you or not, but it is worth a try.

This answer says it only works for IE (I am guessing something like IE 7, no surprise it is VBScript)

---

I found another answer that looks like it is in JavaScript

it is an answer to: [window.print() - without opening the print window [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391232/1214743)

This answer only has 3 votes, and again I haven't tested this either

Comment: i saw this as well. this describes printing the current window, which is not what i want to do. I will be printing a specific image that lives inside the SWF. so i can't use this solution.  i'm looking more for some setting on the OS that disables the print popup. thanks, though.

Comment: you should leave out that you can use JavaScript then, because that is only going to clutter the search

Comment: ok, you're right. removed it from the question. thx.